# What is the best SDN Controller for research purposes?

Tags: python, user-interface, controller, sdn

I am interested in starting my research in the field of SDN. I looked around the internet for which SDN controller is the most suitable for research purposes, but it seems that the SDN community does not agree on a specific controller.

I would like to get advice about which controller is optimum taking into consideration the following:

- Preferably uses Python environment (I am an intermediate Python user but not a professional).
- Provides a decent level documentation as to how to use different network components (I will be simulating a complete network from hosts to core routers).
- Provides a GUI for configuration or at least a graphical representation of the simulated network.
- Best supported with an online community in case of future issues of concepts and connectivity.

During my online research I found that most people recommend POX. Although after setting it up and using its basic functions, I did not feel that it is the most suitable.

Really appreciate your help and time regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are many solutions and what is the best depends on the individual needs.
If you prefer to use Python. Look at the [Ryu](https://osrg.github.io/ryu/) controller if POX does not match your requirements. Ryu is Python based an has a good [documentation](https://osrg.github.io/ryu/resources.html). In combination with [Mininet](http://mininet.org/) and [MiniEdit](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/wiki/Mini-Edit-App) as GUI it perhaps fulfills your requirements. But I think there is no best solution you have to look with which you can work best. Try different solutions ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! just a followup question...in the documentations, tutorials.etc. always the functionality that is described is for a Switch (best case scenario a L3 switch). If I need a more complex network component (e.g. a router, DHCP server, Access Points, Fibre Channel links,etc...), do I have to write the APIs myself or maybe there is ready to use libraries that I can take advantage of ?

Answer (score 1):

In the open source world there are two major players as sdn controller, [ONOS](https://wiki.onosproject.org/display/ONOS/Wiki+Home) and [Opendaylight](https://www.opendaylight.org/). Both are mostly written in java.

Many commercial controllers are based on these two open source controllers.

> Brocade SDN Controller is built directly from OpenDaylight code
>
> Huawei launched the ONOS-based Agile Controller 3.0

They are both big communities, both have active mailing lists and documentation, also UI.

You can find your needs from these controllers.